# How to Prevent JUJU From Overwriting Heat conf File

Tags: juju, openstack, plugins, heat

Installed heat_docker plug-in and need to update "plugin_dirs" in heat.conf, in order for plugin to take effect. This works; however, upon charm update or reboot config file is overwritten. (Unlike, nova charm, where arbitrary parameters can be passed via "config-flags", there doesn't seem to be an equivalent field in heat charm.)
Any thoughts?
Cheers,

Comment: This seems to me to be a Wishlist bug against the heat charm. You should submit a bug against the heat charm asking for this functionality. If needed temporarily you can fork the charm locally to add the functionality yourself, presumably using config-flags in the nova charm as a model.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather **ugly hack** but you could try `chattr +i heat.conf` that is "change attributes add immutable" this would result in no accidental changes to the file. The downside to this approach is that you woud have to issue the command `chattr -i heat.conf` in order to allow any modifications to take place. This approach could easily result in unintended consequences such as normally required modifications to the file would fail unless you removed the immutable attribute before hand. Since this is like opening a can with a machette, I hope someone else has a better answer.